# Converting to .deb or .rpm

Tags: 12.04, deb

Is there any way to convert already installed applications into .deb files? I have to install a lot of applications on multiple computers and my internet is pretty slow (512 Kb/s) so, I can't download and install through terminal.

So, is there any way to convert into .deb or is there any website that has applications in .deb or .rpm or even .tar.gz format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to convert already installed applications into .deb files?

Why so difficult? Your system has all the .DEB files still saved if you did not clear your cached copies. You can find them in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and can copy/paste those to another system and use Ubuntu Software Center to install them.

Besides that your best method would be to use an [apt-cache server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server) if you want to keep these systems updated.

---

My system was installed September 2014 and has all the DEBs I installed myself and more ...

```
/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls -tr
total 96912
unity_7.2.3+14.04.20140826-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
unity-services_7.2.3+14.04.20140826-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libunity-core-6.0-9_7.2.3+14.04.20140826-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk_1%3a0.220.6_all.deb
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_1%3a0.220.6_all.deb
python3-distupgrade_1%3a0.220.6_all.deb
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**RPM:**

You can find almost all the rpm files [here](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/).

**DEB:**

- Debian

  You can find an exhaustive list of **Debian** specific deb files [here](https://packages.debian.org/stable/).
- Ubuntu

  You can find an exhaustive list of **Ubuntu** specific deb files [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: I also downloaded a .rpm file for jre and after I installed it (converted to .deb using alien and then installed using gdebi) I still couldn't use 'java' in the terminal.

Comment: Don't convert packages like that. It will not work most of the times. It is always a good idea to download the proper package. Avoid converting packages.

Answer (score 0):

Some distros such as Mint have a page for distro-specific packages.  It can take some looking to find them but it is possible.  For instance, Mint .deb packages:

http://www.packages.linuxmint.com/

In your case, Mint 13 packages should work without a hitch.